# Problem with getting information of currently configured network interfaces on Linux

Tags: php, linux

I am encountering a problem with string formatting while trying to get only the names of currently configured network interfaces on a Linux Machine.

```
1. <?php
2. $temp = shell_exec("/sbin/ifconfig | cut -b 1-10");
3. echo $temp;                           //Outputs: eth0 lo
4. $arr = explode(" ",$temp);
5. echo "First Location:".$arr[0];         //Outputs: eth0
6. echo "Second Location:".$arr[1];        //Outputs:    
7. echo count($a);                       //Outputs: 165
8. ?>
```

How can i get $arr of size=2 such that
echo $arr[0]; //gives 'eth0'
echo $arr[1]; //gives 'lo'

Thanks a lot

Update:
I thing following command will do the magic for me

```
ifconfig | grep -o -e "[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]*[ ]*Link" | perl -pe "s|^([a-z]*[0-9]*)[ ]*Link|\1|"
```

but i am doing something wrong while executing it from a php file because the browser does not show anything.

```
<?php    
$temp = shell_exec("ifconfig | grep -o -e \"[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]*[ ]*Link\" | perl -pe \"s|^([a-z]*[0-9]*)[ ]*Link|\\1|\"");
echo $temp;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should check the return value to be sure the call exited successfully, but it basically can be done with this:

```
exec('/sbin/ifconfig -s|awk \'{print $1}\'', $interfaces, $returnValue);
array_shift($interfaces);
```

Comment: Nice. :)
but this command returns two elements: 1) eth0 and 2) Iface. What is Iface. I can't see any Iface when i run /sbin/ifconfig in shell.

Comment: Fixed the bug, it should have been `array_shift()`, not `array_pop()`. Run `/sbin/ifconfig -s` and you'll see what the problem was.

Comment: Yeah its short for 'Interface'

Thanks a million. The code is working now. :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can get rid of the whitespace for example this way:

```
explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $temp)));
```

Note that on Linux you can get the info without executing an external command by reading from `/proc/net/dev`.

```
$lines = file('/proc/net/dev');
$interfaces = array();
for ($i = 2; $i < count($lines);  $i++) {
    $line = explode(':', $lines[$i]);
    $interfaces[] = trim($line[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Reading from /proc/net/dev seems nice way to do this but it gives too much info. Can you please tell how may i only access just the names of 'currently configured' interfaces?

Comment: Read the file, split lines, ignore the first two lines, split each line by `:`, take the first part, trim whitespace, add to a list of interfaces.